# Find local mimimum in 2D np.array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sorting

I have this two columns array :

```
A  | 1 
A  | 2
A  | 3
B  | 4
B  | 5
B  | 6
```

where A, B are constants. What I want is to find the mimimum value of each parameter A and B, so the result of this operation would be an other 2D array like this one :

```
A | 1
B | 4
```

I succeed in finding the mimium when only one constant A is present :

```
MIN = np.where(arr == np.amin(arr[:,1]))
output = arr[MIN[0],:]
>> output = A | 1
```

But I can't automatize it when the array is more complex than that. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `np.unique` for extracting the unique values from the first column and then use a boolean mask along the first axis:

```
np.stack([(x, a[a[:, 0] == x, 1].min()) for x in np.unique(a[:, 0])])
```

Alternatively, if you have access to `pandas`, you can create a DataFrame and use `grouby` on the first column:

```
import pandas as pd

result = pd.DataFrame(a).groupby(0).min().values
```

---

Code used for example setup of `a`:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
              [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]).T
```

Comment: Ok thx ! Is there a quick way to access the index of the solutions in the initial array a ? I need these to built the array presented as the solution in my question.

Comment: @aGingerGuy You can add an additional index column to the array, or similarly mask the index in the list comprehension (and use argmin). But in your question you indicate an array with `A, 1` i.e. not taking the index but the first column.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the optional keyword `axis` in the function `np.min`. It allows you to compute the minimum of the array column-wise.
The use of `np.min` is also better than using `np.amin` since it allows you to perform one less step before the result (you immediately have the minimum instead of its index in the table)

Try this :

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]])
np.min(a, axis=1)
# Result : array([1, 4])
```

Comment: When I do that on my two columns array, it prints every value of the second parameter. When I change to 'axis = 0', it prints me the lowest value of the second column, independently of the parameter A and B

Comment: What is the shape of your array exactly